Accuracy issue when exporting from Blender to Sketchfab
Example of model mesh in Blender viewport
Example of model mesh in Sketchfab viewport
I have spent several months modelling, texturing and animating a star wars model in Blender and I am having some difficulty with uploading it to Sketchfab. It is quite a complex model with roughly 176k vertices and detailed armature/animation. The model is high quality and the animation works well in Blender.
Each time I upload the model, most of the smaller details (e.g. greebles, panel lines) on the mesh are contorted as if they have been 'approximated' in some way.
What I do know is that it is connected to the use of my armature. When I have disapplied the armature modifiers on the objects and de-parented them from the armature then uploaded it, the quality of the mesh is correct, as it appears in Blender. Therefore, something is happening to the mesh to deform it in some way when interacting with the armature in the export.
Here are the solutions I have tried already, none of which have solved this problem:

exporting through -> file -> export in blender with fbx, using the default and then changing multiple settings (e.g. the scale to FBX All) to no avail
applying the scale of the objects/armature
exporting using different formats (fbx, blend and obj)
triangulating the quad based mesh
exporting through -> the Sketchfab add-on.
making a new armature and parenting the objects to that.

It would mean a lot if someone could help me export this model onto Sketchfab!
Cheers

Could it be possible that your model is way to small/big and you are getting some float issue ? If you get the same issue with all the situations you listed above, I'm guessing the issue is on the Sketchfab side. Did you try opening your exported model with another software (like the 3D Viewer of Windows) ?

@Lutzi both the model and the armature have normal sizes of around 5-20m in width/depth/length. I think you are right that it is something on Sketchfab's side; I tried a gltf file to view it in the windows 3D viewer as you suggest and it seems to have retained the mesh quality and kept the armature/animation.

As it stands this doesn't seem to be an issue with Blender itself, so I've voted to close the question. If you happen to find any further details that indicate otherwise please edit your post so it can be reopened.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I have just tried to view the fbx file in Autodesk and the programme stated that the animation data is corrupted and couldn't play it; I think there may still be something going wrong with the exporting of the animation/armature in Blender then?

If you remove all animations from the model and export it do the issues still manifest?

Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

When you have further details please edit them into the original question, avoid posting them in the comments section. An issue of this complexity is also impossible to diagnose from two screenshots alone. Anticipating what you will likely be asked next I'd encourage you to post an example file experts can test with
